# I want to hover the icons to white with sass (without filter)

Tags: css, svg, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

```
$cwhite : "fff";
$cblack : "000";
$icon-bg1 : "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='58.045' height='58.044' viewBox='0 0 58.045 58.044'%3E%3Cpath id='usericon' d='M29.022.563A29.022,29.022,0,1,0,58.044,29.585,29.017,29.017,0,0,0,29.022.563Zm0,11.234a10.3,10.3,0,1,1-10.3,10.3A10.3,10.3,0,0,1,29.022,11.8Zm0,40.257a22.425,22.425,0,0,1-17.144-7.981,13.048,13.048,0,0,1,11.527-7,2.864,2.864,0,0,1,.831.129,15.494,15.494,0,0,0,4.786.807,15.435,15.435,0,0,0,4.786-.807,2.863,2.863,0,0,1,.831-.129,13.048,13.048,0,0,1,11.527,7A22.425,22.425,0,0,1,29.022,52.054Z' transform='translate(0 -0.563)' fill='%23#{$cblack}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E";
$icon-bg2 : "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='24' viewBox='0 0 30 24'%3E%3Cpath id='refreshicon' d='M15,3A11.967,11.967,0,0,0,7.207,5.875a1,1,0,1,0,1.3,1.52A10,10,0,0,1,24.951,14H22l4,6,4-6H26.949A12.012,12.012,0,0,0,15,3ZM4,10,0,16H3.051a11.993,11.993,0,0,0,19.742,8.125,1,1,0,1,0-1.3-1.52A10,10,0,0,1,5.049,16H8Z' transform='translate(0 -3)' fill='%23#{$cblack}' /%3E%3C/svg%3E";

@mixin sidbarIco($backImg , $fill-hover){
    background-image:url($backImg);
    // &:hover{
        // what code?   
    // }
}

.sidbar .ico{
    display: block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
.sidbar .ico-1{@include sidbarIco($icon-bg1 , $cwhite)}
.sidbar .ico-2{@include sidbarIco($icon-bg2 , $cwhite)}
```

I have a sidebar that contains 2 icons.
I used svg for icons.
I changed the color of svg with a variable and its default is black.
I also want to change the hover color with a variable.
used "fill='%23#{$cblack}" in content svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to use the css [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) property to play with the color of your svg that is inserted as a background image:

So first replace yours colors variable with css valid ones:

```css
$cwhite : #fff;
$cblack : #000;
```

Then use `mask-image` in your `sidbarIco` function:

```css
@mixin sidbarIco($backImg , $fill-hover){
    background-color: $cblack;
    -webkit-mask-image: url($backImg);
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    &:hover{
      background-color: $fill-hover;
    }
}
```

Check [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/51Lmdpr6/11/) to see it in action.

Here is the compiled example:

```css
.sidbar .ico {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.sidbar .ico-1 {
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='58.045' height='58.044' viewBox='0 0 58.045 58.044'%3E%3Cpath id='usericon' d='M29.022.563A29.022,29.022,0,1,0,58.044,29.585,29.017,29.017,0,0,0,29.022.563Zm0,11.234a10.3,10.3,0,1,1-10.3,10.3A10.3,10.3,0,0,1,29.022,11.8Zm0,40.257a22.425,22.425,0,0,1-17.144-7.981,13.048,13.048,0,0,1,11.527-7,2.864,2.864,0,0,1,.831.129,15.494,15.494,0,0,0,4.786.807,15.435,15.435,0,0,0,4.786-.807,2.863,2.863,0,0,1,.831-.129,13.048,13.048,0,0,1,11.527,7A22.425,22.425,0,0,1,29.022,52.054Z' transform='translate(0 -0.563)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sidbar .ico-1:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.sidbar .ico-2 {
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='24' viewBox='0 0 30 24'%3E%3Cpath id='refreshicon' d='M15,3A11.967,11.967,0,0,0,7.207,5.875a1,1,0,1,0,1.3,1.52A10,10,0,0,1,24.951,14H22l4,6,4-6H26.949A12.012,12.012,0,0,0,15,3ZM4,10,0,16H3.051a11.993,11.993,0,0,0,19.742,8.125,1,1,0,1,0-1.3-1.52A10,10,0,0,1,5.049,16H8Z' transform='translate(0 -3)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sidbar .ico-2:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class='sidbar'>
  <li class='ico ico-1'></li>
  <li class='ico ico-2'></li>
</ul>
```